# Secure Connection Failed : The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified

Tags: firefox

Secure Connection Failed : The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

FireFox browser responds like this what we should do?

firefox version : 89.0 (64-bit)

this link has issue [click here](https://www.kig.ae/ajctest/)

Comment: Can you include more details like if that is the error when you visited a site that you are responsible for?

Comment: Secure Connection Failed:

An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

    ->The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
   -> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Even did not change any thing before it was working fine